# How to get the hour and the nearest hour?

Tags: php, time, hour

How do you get the current hour and the nearest hour, e.g.

The time is now **`2:25PM`**.

The current hour is **`2:00PM`**

The nearest hour to be **`2:59PM`** (not `3PM`, as `2:59PM` will do).

Comment: Lol, it's not homework. I'm not currently in education. ;-)

Comment: Why is the nearest hour 2:59? instead of 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [date](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function :

```
$current = date("g:00A");
$next = date("g:59A");
```

If you want the real time :

```
$now = date("g:iA");
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly:

```
<?php
$hour = date("g:00A"); // or "G" for 24-hour clock
$nearest_hour = date("g:59A");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
$hour = date('H');
$min = date('i');

if($min > 30)
{
  $closest_hour = $hour +1;
}
elseif($min < 30)
{
  $closest_hour = $hour;
}
else
{
  //Here is exactly half past $hour so you decide what to do :)
}
```

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

So you have HH:MM.

Why just keep HH and add 59 next to it ? Isn't that work all the time ?